# 2D Color coded scatter plot with user defined color range and static colormap

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have 3 vectors - `x`,`y`,`vel` each having some 8k values. I also have quite a few files containing these 3 vectors. All the files have different x,y,vel. I want to get multiple scatter plots with the following conditions:

1. Color coded according to the 3rd variable i.e vel.
2. Once the ranges have been set for the colors (for the data from the 1st file), they should remain constant for all the remaining files. i don't want a dynamically changing (color code changing with each new file).
3. Want to plot a colorbar.

I greatly appreciate all your thoughts!!

I have attached the code for a single file.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create Map
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu')
x,y,vel = np.loadtxt('finaldata_temp.txt', skiprows=0, unpack=True)
vel = [cm(float(i)/(8000)) for i in xrange(8000)] # 8000 is the no. of values in each of x,y,vel vectors.

# 2D Plot
plt.scatter(x, y, s=27, c=vel, marker='o')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.savefig('testfig.png', dpi=300)
plt.show()
quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to iterate over all your data files to get the maximum value for `vel`, I have added a few lines of code (that need to be adjusted to fit your case) that will do that.

Therefore, your `colorbar` line has been changed to use the `max_vel`, allowing you to get rid of that code using the fixed value of `8000`.

Additionally, I took the liberty to remove the black edges around the points, because I find that they 'obfuscate' the color of the point.

Lastly, I have added adjusted your plot code to use an `axis` object, which is required to have a colorbar.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# This is needed to iterate over your data files
import glob 

# Loop over all your data files to get the maximum value for 'vel'. 
# You will have to adjust this for your code
"""max_vel = 0
for i in glob.glob(<your files>,'r') as fr:
    # Iterate over all lines
    if <vel value> > max_vel:
        max_vel = <vel_value>"""

# Create Map
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu')
x,y,vel = np.loadtxt('finaldata_temp.txt', skiprows=0, unpack=True)

# Plot the data
fig=plt.figure()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
# Here we switch to an axis object
# Additionally, you can plot several of your files in the same figure using
# the subplot option.
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
s = ax.scatter(x,y,c=vel,edgecolor=''))
# Here we assign the color bar to the axis object
cb = plt.colorbar(mappable=s,ax=ax,cmap=cm)
# Here we set the range of the color bar based on the maximum observed value
# NOTE: This line only changes the calculated color and not the display 
# 'range' of the legend next to the plot, for that we need to switch to 
# ColorbarBase (see second code snippet).
cb.setlim(0,max_vel)
cb.set_label('Value of \'vel\'')
plt.show()
```

Snippet, demonstrating `ColorbarBase`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu')
x = [1,5,10]
y = [2,6,9]
vel = [7,2,1]

# Plot the data
fig=plt.figure()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
s = ax.scatter(x,y,c=vel,edgecolor=''))
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=10)
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.95, 0.1, 0.01, 0.8])
cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax1,norm=norm,cmap=cm,orientation='vertical')
cb.set_clim(vmin = 0, vmax = 10)
cb.set_label('Value of \'vel\'')
plt.show()
```

This produces the following plot

[image: Matplotlib plot of sample data using ColorbarBase]

For more examples of what you can do with the `colorbar`, specifically the more flexible `ColorbarBase`, I would suggest that you check the documentation -> http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/colorbar_only.html

Comment: Yeah adding the vmax and vmin solved the problem :)
But another one has cropped up now. This code ignores my colormap (RdBu_r here) and gets a different particular map, every time,  by default. Ant ideas how to change it?


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create Map
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdBu_r')
#RdYlBu
x,y,vel = np.loadtxt('finaldata.txt', skiprows=0, unpack=True)

# 2D plot
plt.scatter(x, y, s=27, c=vel, vmin=0, vmax=0.09, marker='o')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.colorbar()
plt.savefig('testfig.png', dpi=400)

Comment: That is because in that snippet you are not passing your `cm` to the `colorbar`, change your `plt.colorbar()` line to `plt.colorbar(cmap=cm)` as I have done in the first example. I suggest that you just take either of my two example snippets and go from there, that would have prevented this last mistake.